# What do you call a cycle which is used to sell items on its back on the roads?

Tags: names

I want to know what a cycle is called which one uses to sell items on the road at the back of the cycle.

Comment: The term is a *trade bike*. Or at least that used always to be the name for one with steel carrier at the front, used 50 years ago for taking goods door to door.

Comment: Note that such bikes are essentially unknown in the US, except perhaps in a few quarters of New York City, Philadelphia, etc.

Comment: You'll probably have to narrow the field. The generic name is 'cargo bike'; in the UK, these were known as butcher's bikes (although the Royal Mail had the largest fleet). Anyway, there's quite a variety, and quite a variety of names. Currently in the US, 'long-tail bikes' are popular for delivery, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean **Bicycle Trailer** or **Bicycle cart** ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_trailer))

> A bicycle trailer is a motorless wheeled frame with a hitch system for
>   transporting cargo by bicycle.

or simply,
**Cart** can also be used ([Source](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=meaning%20of%20cart))

> a strong open vehicle with **two** or four wheels, typically used for carrying loads and pulled by a horse.